# It is possible to configure Rollup to ignore dynamic imports from specified functions?

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

I have some code which runs on both client and the server. It kind of looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
    async initializeNodeEnvironment() {
        await import(variableWithSpecifier);
    }
    async initializeWebEnvironment() {
        await import('./WebEnvironment.js');
    }
}
```

I would like to have Rollup basically act like the `initializeNodeEnvironment()` function does not exist and not import anything in the function.

I could not find a plugin which would accomplish this, specifically because I am using a variable to specify my server-side imports. If this does not exist I am willing to write a plugin to do this, I think it would look something like this:

```
functionsToIgnore: [{
    scriptPath: '/path-to-script.js',
    functionName: 'initializeNodeEnvironment',
}]
```

I'll skip writing a plugin if this functionality can already be accomplished in an existing way.

Thanks!

Comment: Is [Treeshaking functionnality](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#tree-shaking) of rollup doing the job?

Comment: @Troopers it isn't, I ended up writing my own plugin: https://github.com/system-inc/framework/blob/master/system/interface/graphical/web/transpiler/RollupWebTranspiler.js#L281